# How to add max running threads (concurrent users) value in JMeter HTML Dashboard along with Start Time & End Time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am using JMeter 5.6.2 and looking to customize the JMeter HTML report dashboard. In the "Test and Report information" of Dashboard it would be good to have the max active threads (concurrent users) that the load test achieved. Is it possible to refer the max value of "allThreads" column of JTL/CSV results file in HTML dashboard by modifying 'js' script and content files in "report-template" folder of JMeter directory? Please advise.

Also, I managed to hide the APDEX table by modifying "index.html.fmkr" properties. In place of it could we show Active Threads over time graph in the dashboard just beside Requests Summary showing a pie chart of PASS/FAIL requests?

[Expected JMeter HTML Dashboard Modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37IYX.png)

Customizing JMeter HTML Dashboard report.